# Expand a function in my own basis

Tags: calculus

Consider the basis

$$\{ sin^2(k\pi x)\}_{k=1}^{\infty }$$

I want to expand the following function with this basis in interval $[0,1]$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 4x & 0<x<\frac{1}{4}\\ 
\frac{4}{3}-\frac{4}{3}x &\frac{1}{4}<x<1\\ 0 & o.w. \end{cases}
$$

My problem is this basis is not orthogonal and I don't know how to do this when the basis is not orthogonal?

Comment: [Like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Comment: @J.G. I knew about that but how can i do this for functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f_k:=\sin^2k\pi x=\frac12(1-\cos 2k\pi x)$ so the inner product $\langle g|h\rangle:=\int_0^1 g^\ast(x)h(x)dx$ satisfies $\int_0^1\cos 2m\pi xdx=\delta_{m0}$ for $m\in\Bbb Z$ in terms of the Kronecker delta, and$$\begin{align}\langle f_k|f_l\rangle&=\frac18\int_0^1(2-2\cos 2k\pi x-2\cos 2l\pi x+\cos 2(k-l)\pi x-\cos 2(k+l)\pi x)dx\\&=\frac18(2+\delta_{kl}).\end{align}$$What follows is so much work I suspect there's a better choice of inner product for this problem, but I'll try to keep this answer succinct. The above results can be thought of as the elements of a symmetric infinite-dimensional matrix $M$, viz. $M_{kl}=\langle f_k|f_l\rangle$. Suppose $f=\sum_kc_kf_k$, and define a vector $v$ with entries $v_l:=\langle f|f_l\rangle=\sum_kc_kM_{kl}$. Integrating by parts,$$\begin{align}v_l&=2\int_0^{1/4}x(1-\cos2l\pi x)dx+\frac23\int_{1/4}^1(1-x)(1-\cos2l\pi x)dx\\&=\frac14+\frac{4}{3\pi^2l^2}\sin^2\frac{\pi l}{4}\end{align}$$(see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%281-cos%282l*pi*x%29%29+from+0+to+1%2F4) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281-x%29*%281-cos%282l*pi*x%29%29+from+1%2F4+to+1)). Next we rearrange$$v_l=\sum_kc_kM_{kl}=\sum_kc_k\frac18(2+\delta_{kl})=\frac18\left(2\sum_kc_k+c_l\right)$$to$$2\sum_kc_k+c_l=8v_l=2+\frac{32}{3\pi^2l^2}\sin^2\frac{\pi l}{4}.$$[You can show](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+%28sin%28pi*l%2F4%29%29%5E2%2Fl%5E2+from+1+to+infinity) with the Basel problem's solution that$$\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{32}{3\pi^2k^2}\sin^2\frac{\pi k}{4}=1,$$so the solution is $c_l=\frac{32}{3\pi^2l^2}\sin^2\frac{\pi l}{4}$. Just to explain the above sum, $\sin^2\frac{\pi k}{4}$ is $0$ if $4|k$, $1$ if $k/2$ is odd or $\frac12$ if $k$ is odd. Hence$$\sum_{k\ge1}\sin^2\frac{\pi k}{4}=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(4j-2)^2}+\sum_{j\in\Bbb N\setminus2\Bbb N}\frac{1}{2j^2}=\frac34\sum_{j\in\Bbb N\setminus2\Bbb N}\frac{1}{j^2}\stackrel{\ast}{=}\frac34\frac{\pi^2}{8}=\frac{3\pi^2}{32},$$where $\ast$ uses [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Reciprocals_of_Squares_of_Odd_Integers).

Comment: Thank, but I cant understand part you said cl+2sum=8vl?

Comment: @SaniaSadian That comes from rearranging $v=Mc$.

Comment: can you say it in form of series? not matrices.

Comment: @SaniaSadian See edit.

Comment: thanks a lot. and how do I can rearrange sigma in Basel form?

Comment: @SaniaSadian I've made another edit to address that.